# C# multiple ip addresses on one network interface

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

All we know that PC can have one or more network interfaces. Each network interface can have one or two (maybe more) ip addresses. The problem is how to determine which ip address will be used to communicate with remote host.

I know how to get network interface using next code (thank's guys from pinvoke.net):

```
private static NetworkInterface GetNetworkInterfaceByIndex(uint index)
{
    // Search in all network interfaces that support IPv4.
    NetworkInterface ipv4Interface = (from thisInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                                      where thisInterface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)
                                      let ipv4Properties = thisInterface.GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties()
                                      where ipv4Properties != null && ipv4Properties.Index == index
                                      select thisInterface).SingleOrDefault();
    if (ipv4Interface != null)
        return ipv4Interface;

    // Search in all network interfaces that support IPv6.
    NetworkInterface ipv6Interface = (from thisInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                                      where thisInterface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6)
                                      let ipv6Properties = thisInterface.GetIPProperties().GetIPv6Properties()
                                      where ipv6Properties != null && ipv6Properties.Index == index
                                      select thisInterface).SingleOrDefault();

    return ipv6Interface;
}

[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetBestInterface(uint DestAddr, out uint BestIfIndex);

static void IpAddressLogTest()
{
    Console.Write("Enter IP address to choose interface: ");
    IPAddress addr;
    IPAddress.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out addr);
    uint bestintf;
    var res = GetBestInterface(BitConverter.ToUInt32(addr.GetAddressBytes(), 0), out bestintf);
    NetworkInterface interfaceInfo = GetNetworkInterfaceByIndex(bestintf);
    foreach (var a in interfaceInfo.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
       if (a.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            Console.WriteLine(a.Address.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This code works perfectly and i know what interface will be used to communicate with host. But interface can have two ip addresses in different networks.

How in that case to choose right ip address?

UPD1. Example of such settings:

[image]

Comment: By the subnet mask.  The routing in the PC uses standard protocol and take the route with the shortest mask.  So a mask of 255.255.255.0 is used as the route before a mask of 255.255.0.0.

Comment: @jdweng, mask is the same for the both ip addresses. see update 1

Comment: What you have is fine for subnet 20 and 208.  When you go to any other subnet there is an issue because the masks are the same.  So normally the default route (one going to the internet) should use 0.0.0.0 so all other IP get routed to the default.